# Go switch fallthrough

Tags: go

I am trying to understand the switch/fallthrough keyword. Using fallthrough statement in a switch block means the next block is entered even if the expression doesn't match but this is only valid when there has already been a match right? The code below seems to work that way but I just want to be sure.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    integer := 5
    switch integer {
    case 4:
        fmt.Println("integer <= 4")
        fallthrough
    case 5:
        fmt.Println("integer <= 5")
        fallthrough
    case 6:
        fmt.Println("integer <= 6")
        fallthrough
    case 7:
        fmt.Println("integer <= 7")
        fallthrough
    case 8:
        fmt.Println("integer <= 8")
        fallthrough
    default:
        fmt.Println("default case")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The fallthrough statement transfers control to the next case clause in an expression switch.  The expression on the next case is not considered when transferring control.

The [specification says this about the fallthrough statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Fallthrough_statements):

> A "fallthrough" statement transfers control to the first statement of the next case clause in an expression "switch" statement. It may be used only as the final non-empty statement in such a clause.

and this about [expression switches](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Expression_switches):

> In a case or default clause, the last non-empty statement may be a (possibly labeled) "fallthrough" statement to indicate that control should flow from the end of this clause to the first statement of the next clause. Otherwise control flows to the end of the "switch" statement. A "fallthrough" statement may appear as the last statement of all but the last clause of an expression switch.

Answer (score 2):

That's right. The `fallthrough` statement causes it to go from the last statement on a case clause to the first statement of the next skipping the later case evaluation. From the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements):

> In a case or default clause, the last non-empty statement may be a
>   (possibly labeled) "fallthrough" statement to indicate that control
>   should flow from the end of this clause to the first statement of the
>   next clause. Otherwise control flows to the end of the "switch"
>   statement. A "fallthrough" statement may appear as the last statement
>   of all but the last clause of an expression switch.